# youtube api TopicId translating?

Tags: python

So I have `topicIds` for a video

```
[u'/m/0lbxz:/m/04rlf', u'/m/06m6j', u'/m/017bqr', u'/m/05r5c'].
```

I am trying to translate the list into something like `[people, children...]`

Is there an API call that takes in a `topicID` and returns the pertaining topic?

Answer (score 0):

Those are Freebase topics and you can retrieve them using the Freebase topic API https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview you can also dump and build your own local dataset using freebase dumps https://developers.google.com/freebase/data

However I would advise caution on using this, as freebase API has been deprecated.

At any case, here is a simple example on how to retrieve the data that you are looking for

```
$ curl "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=/m/06m6j&indent=true"

{
  "status": "200 OK",
  "result": [
    {
      "mid": "/m/06m6j",
      "id": "/en/ragtime",
      "name": "Ragtime",
      "notable": {
        "name": "Musical genre",
        "id": "/music/genre"
      },
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 20.126026
    }
  ],
  "cost": 4,
  "hits": 1
}
```